# Webpack Error with Kendo-angular2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, webpack, kendo-ui-angular2

After long time waiting for the Angular2 Kendo UI Beta, we just try to add it to our project. But it seems that there is a problem, while building with webpack. The console of the browser shows the following error:

> Unexpected value 'ButtonsModule' imported by the module 'AppModule' (compiler.umd.js:14126)

We also tried the quickstart from this link:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2-quickstart

As soon as we converted the sample project to build by webpack, the same error occurs. Does anybody have an idea what to do?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are proposing a solution or just promoting your product, Cagatay?

Answer (score 0):

now we fixed it. It was an version problem, after updating all packages to the newest version, it works now.

Comment: Hi, can you share which version you used to get it working?

Comment: For sure! Here the excerpt of my package json:

    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.10.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^0.5.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^0.10.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^0.10.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.3.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^0.10.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^0.10.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^0.10.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview": "^0.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-sortable": "^0.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^0.9.0",